# Kerberos authentication

Tags: browser, browser-add-ons

Does the android web browser support kerberos authentication?  If not, is there an open source web browser for android that works well, which can be extended to support kerberos?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not.  Unfortunately all the major Android browsers that I know of -- Firefox, Opera, Dolphin, Skyfire -- don't appear to support it either.  Firefox does support NTLM, and I'd expect it to support kerberos sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chrome M46 and later versions support Kerberos on Android, and I think its the only web browser that supports SPNEGO/GSSAPI/Kerberos on Android.

Lately, the Google repo at Github published a stand-alone [client app for Kerberos](https://github.com/google/android-kerberos-authenticator). It's provided as a reference implementation; yet, I think it can be used in production with some caution. Below are some resources I have found that you might find helpful:

- [Writing a SPNEGO Authenticator for Chrome on Android](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/http-authentication/writing-a-spnego-authenticator-for-chrome-on-android): This page describes the interface between Chrome and the SPNEGO Authenticator.
- [Test DPC App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc): You may need this app to set managed configurations for both Chrome and the Kerberos client
- [Kerberos Test Utils](https://doss-gitlab.eidos.ic.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/sneeze/chromium/tree/master/tools/android/kerberos): Simple app and scripts used to test Kerberos auth on Chrome and WebView.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own Spnego Authenticator you can also go for a commercial solution like www.hypergate.com

Answer (score 0):

Firefox supports kerberos authentication I believe. You need to change the settings in `About -> config`

Comment: Can you support this opinion by giving a source proving it?